# Django with cassandra - No schema for cassandra database

Tags: django, cassandra

I'm trying to setup cassandra with django using the instructions [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-cassandra-engine/).

Everything works fine. When I migrate, the table is getting created. But when I run the server using `python manage.py runserver`, it gives me the following error:

```
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
Unhandled exception in thread started by Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "/Users/gpallav/Env/tp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py",
 line 228, in wrapper fn(*args, **kwargs) 
File "/Users/gpallav/Env/tp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py",
 line 128, in inner_run self.check_migrations() 
File "/Users/gpallav/Env/tp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py",
 line 422, in check_migrations executor = MigrationExecutor(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS]) 
File "/Users/gpallav/Env/tp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py",
 line 20, in init self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection) 
File "/Users/gpallav/Env/tp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py",
 line 52, in init self.build_graph() 
File "/Users/gpallav/Env/tp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py",
 line 209, in build_graph self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations() 
File "/Users/gpallav/Env/tp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py",
 line 65, in applied_migrations self.ensure_schema() 
File "/Users/gpallav/Env/tp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py",
 line 57, in ensure_schema editor.create_model(self.Migration) 
File "/Users/gpallav/Env/tp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_cassandra_engine/base/schema.py",
 line 23, in create_model raise Exception('No schema for cassandra database')
```

Plz help!

Comment: do you run `cassandra -f` on back ground?

did you read [use-cassandra-on-django](https://www.slothparadise.com/how-to-install-and-use-cassandra-on-django/)

Comment: @BearBrown yes, cassandra is running in the background. And yes, I have read and followed this link.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug of django-cassandra-engine(1.2.1).

Now it's fixed in django-cassandra-engine(1.2.2).

You can upgrade your django-cassandra-engine:

`pip install --upgrage django-cassandra-engine`